# Is Serrated Pick a versatile weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons

There seems to be some discrepancy in the serrated pick, it's listed as a 1-handed weapon, yet it has the 'Small' property, which is only applicable to versatile and 2-handed weapons so far as I know.
It's in an odd niche, as it has D10 damage vs the War Pick's D8, but it is a small 1-handed weapon vs the War Pick's Small Versatile.

Comment: There are other 1d10 1 handed weapons...

Comment: No the best comment was just a little hyperbole from me. I've removed it to clarify the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Small* weapon property isn't *"only applicable"* to versatile or two-handed weapons (unless it's a *huge* oversight, there's at least three other one-handers that don't have the versatile property as well), it simply allows a small creature access to a two-handed weapon or, in the case of one-handed weapons, it allows them to use it as a versatile weapon.

This does not limit the weapon to *only* small creatures though: note that a shortbow (I know it's a two-handed weapon but the same rules apply) has the *Small* property yet can be used by medium or larger creatures.

So, using the *Serrated Pick* as an example, it can be used one-handed by small or larger creatures but can only be used as a *versatile* weapon by small creatures.
Unlike the *War Pick* which has both the *Small* and *Versatile* properties. This means it can be used one-handed by small or larger creatures and *both* can use it as a *versatile* weapon.

Comment: how does this work with a small one-handed weapon, i.e. is it 1-handed only for small characters? (worth mentioning because it's what the question deals with)

Comment: It was never clear that small=versatile for small characters. That's really interesting